# How do I connect my Navigation Controller to every screen of my storyboard?

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am using Swift and Xcode 6.1.1, I used a navigation controller in my story board and set it as the initial view. I have a sign up screen and a login screen and I use buttons to navigate with segues between them. After the user logs in I segue to the main app view but how would I do this using my navigation controller.

In my app delegate `didFinishLoadingWithOptions` is create a `var navController = UINavigationController()` but how do I let this variable connect with the navigation controller in my Storyboard. I want to be able to set new views as the root view once an action has succeeded like a successful login.

I am still learning alot about iOS development please explain like I am a 5 year old.

Answer (score 3):

you don't have to manual create a `UINavigationController` in "app delegate".
as you said,you have edit "initial view controller" setting  in "Interface builder" already! so when the app startup,the "initial view controller"(also UINavigationController,as you set) is created automatic!

All you have to do is create a relationship bettween the first UINavigationController(login view) with another UIViewController(login sucess view).

How to do this?
Just hold "control" key and from "UINavigationController" drag a blue line to the "login sucess UIViewController",and select "init root viewcontroller" in "releationship segue" section at the popmenu!

you can read this article for more detail
[enter storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)